# Create ZonedDateTime values with default values causes DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, date, zoneddatetime

my goal is create a method that parse dates from Strings, both string and pattern are given as parameters, but some of the date strings does not contain any time values, so in my method i set default time values to current time values stored in variable 'now', but i am having some troubles parsing dates like this `10 may 2020 7:15 am`. the code i use to parse the dates looks like this

```
    @Test 
    public void patronFechaZDT(){
    String strFecha = "10 may 2020 7:15 am";
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
            DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd MMMM yyyy h:mm a")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, now.getHour())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, now.getMinute())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, now.getSecond())
            .toFormatter(Locale.US)
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    TemporalAccessor accessor = dtf1.parse(strFecha, new ParsePosition(0));
    ZonedDateTime fecha = ZonedDateTime.from(accessor);

    System.out.println("str: " + strFecha + ", fecha: " + fecha );
}
```

The output of the code above is

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10 may 2020 7:15 am' could not be parsed: Conflict found: HourOfDay 16 differs from HourOfDay 7 while resolving  AmPmOfDay
```

I alrready noticed the problem is the default value 'HOUR_OF_DAY' which causes conflict with the hour captured in the string, and removing the line `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, now.getHour())`, my code runs well

The main problem is that my method will recive a lot of patterns and strings, and some of this patterns will not contain time values, or zone values, and i really want to parse the dates using default time values, so if it is posile i want to keep the line `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, now.getHour())`, thanks in advance.

**Edit**

As @akuzminykh sugested, i add the correct ChronoField `CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM` and my DateTimeFormatter now looks like this:

```
    int hour = now.getHour(); int am = 0;
    if(hour > 12){
        hour = hour - 12;
        am = 1;
    }

    DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, am)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, hour)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, now.getHour())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, now.getMinute())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, now.getSecond())
            .toFormatter(Locale.US)
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

But, unless i coment the line `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY...` this new Formatter produces the same exception. Any help willl be apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you parse `h`, which is for *clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)* (see [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)), you of course have to use the correct `ChronoField` for your `parseDefaulting`. Check out [`ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html). What you need is `ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM`.

Comment: ohh i catch the idea now!!, there is a way to set default values for both CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM and ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY in the same Builder?. For example if find the value of hh inside the String, then ignores default for HH?

Comment: @FernandoCT Of course you can. The formatter will take whatever is specified by the pattern.

Comment: ok, i add the correct default ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, the problem persist unless i remove the default for HOUR_OF_DAY, i edit my question, if you can catch anymore would be great

Comment: @FernandoCT I was too unclear in the comment: You can use both, in regard of the correct pattern, but not both at once. When you have both, how can the formatter decide, what the hour should be? This is exactly what the error is telling you. When your pattern already provides information about the hour from `h`, what is it supposed to do with the default value for `H`? That's the problem, you give it basically two different hours to create a `ZonedDateTime`. Is it clear now?